# Call a method of an activity(UNKNOWN) from a class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to call a method which is defined in activityA, activityB and activityC from a non-activity class. I want to call a method of ONLY any one of the activities.
e.g. activity.method(), where activity is either activityA or activityB or activityC.

```
((Object) this.context)).method();
```

In above line I need to specify an `Object` of an activity. How can I determine the the object at run time where I have activity's Context?

**Note :** In real, I have such 10-15 activities.

Comment: I think better way to define static method in A,B,C activity and call appropriate activity method.

Comment: Is far as I could understand, you need a global method. Why don't you just declare it as public static in some non-Activity class? If you need to use an Activity instance in the method, just add it as parameter e.g. myMethod(Activity a) and pass this when calling it from a certain Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion :

1. Create an interface with your "method()" signature.
2. Let all the activities implement that interface.
3. Once getting the context, you could typecast your activity to that interface and call the "method()".
4. Do remember, perform the typecast in a try-catch block, so that if in case you get to a scenario where you try to call the method on an activity which doesn't implemented the interface, you can handle the TypeCastException safely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a doubt with its implementation. Consider that I have 10 activities in total. I have an interface `myInterface` and it is implemented by activityA, activityB and activityC. When I call `myInterface`'s method `myMethod()`, it will call `myMethod()` defined in all of three activities. This is a problem. I want to call a method defined in an activity whose `Context` I have.

Comment: This problem can be addressed easily.Assume ActA, ActB, ActC (all implement the interface (MyInterface), each of these activities need to have there own implementation of myMethod(). When you call ActA.myMethod(), the call will go to that specific activity e.g. ActA in this case. Expanding the example further, if you need a common implementation of myMethod, in that case you can create MyInterface as an abstract class rather than an interface and give the common implementation to the abstract base class i.e. (MyInterface) and special implementation in the actual activity class.

Answer (score 1):

Below code might help you

```
if(context instanceof ActivityA)
((ActivityA) this.context)).method();
else if(context instanceof ActivityB)
((ActivityB) this.context)).method();
else if(context instanceof ActivityC)
((ActivityC) this.context)).method();
```

Comment: This solution might not be a good fit, if the number of activities/objects on which the method needs to be called increases.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then using listener or abstract base class you can achieve this.